# Rotate through simple vertical tab menu content on timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, tabs

I'm using w3schools's vertical tab menu to create a "How it works" menu like this: https://www.canva.com/graphs/

How can I loop through each tab to show the tabcontent div on a timer (while still letting users click the tabs and manually navigate)?

**Thank you for any help!**

The code from w3schools's vertical tabs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Vertical Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout` to create a timer that will move your tabs. Here is the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Vertical Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks london" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks paris" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks tokyo" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
// Create a list of classes for each button
var cities = ["london", "paris", "tokyo"];
var cityIndex = 0;
// Time in miliseconds for the rotation
var rotationInterval = 2000;

// This will find the correct button, click on it, and move to the next one
function rotateCity(index) {
    var currentCityButton = document.querySelector("." + cities[index]);
    currentCityButton.click();
    // Recursive call
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (cityIndex < 2) {
            cityIndex++;
        } else {
            cityIndex = 0;
        }
        rotateCity(cityIndex);
    }, rotationInterval);
}

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Start rotation
rotateCity(cityIndex)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And [this is a working example](https://codepen.io/brunomont/pen/ExYGdLR?editors=1000).

Comment: is there a way to add an extra delay if someone clicks on a tab (so it pauses longer before rotating)? I tried adding a different rotation interval, but no luck

Comment: Yes! You could store the `setTimeout` in a variable and use `clearTimeout` to reset the time. I updated the CodePen with that: https://codepen.io/brunomont/pen/ExYGdLR?editors=1000
The changes are a new variable (`timeoutFunction`) and some code to reset the timeout inside `openCity()`